# Add wp_header depending on wp_content in Wordpress Plugin

Tags: wordpress

I am developing a Wordpress plugin to run a certain javascript function based on some parameters.

The first step is to include the javascript file from my server. Easy:

```
add_action('wp_head', 'my_plugin_head');

function my_plugin_head(){
echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.my-server.net/js/w.js" ></script>';
}
```

The *second* step is to change certain text in the WordPress body to the javascript function...something like:

```
 add_filter('the_content', 'plugin_text_replace');
 function plugin_text_replace($text){
 $text=preg_replace('blah', 'blah');

 return $text;
 //I Am still researching how to setup the preg_replace. 
 //It will look for something like plugin_call[1, 40, 60]
 //And Change it To jsFunction(1, 40, 60);
 //Bonus for anyone who can help me with that :)
 }
```

In any case, I realized that I want the my-server.net javascript included ONLY if needed (or in other words, only if the preg_replace found a match). This is problematic to me because I can't find anyway to add a script to the `<head>` tag without using an action on `wp_head`, which does not have any reference to the body of the text.

How can I add a header ONLY if a certain preg_match is found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add javascript the best way is using `wp_enqueue_script()`, like this:

```
function my_scripts_method() {
    wp_enqueue_script('my_java_function');            
}    

// For use on the Front end (ie. Theme)
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');
```

Inserting code into the `<body>` can be achieved like this:

```
function wp_body() {
  do_action( 'wp_body' );
}

add_action( 'wp_body', 'my_body_function' ) ; // 

// In "header.php" place something like this after <body>:

if ( function_exists('wp_body')) wp_body(); ?>
```